# Orientation for Lebesgue integrals

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

In standard Riemannian integration theory some sort of orientation is defined due to the addition of a minus sign when one switches the limits of integration. In the integration theory on manifolds, an orientation is also provided by the volume form on the manifold.

But in the theory of Lebesgue it doesn't seem to matter because the integration is based on the measure of a set and this is orientation independent. In the literature I found that they do sometimes add some kind of convention when we integrate over intervals (or higher dimensional generalizations) just as in the theory of Riemann. But this feels a bit forced.

Is there any formal way to deduce an orientation based on the properties of the Lebesgue integral? And if not, how does one unite both theories with respect to this concept?

Comment: There is no orientation in Lebesgue theory because there is not necessarily an ordering on an abstract measure space. Instead of integrating "from $a$ to $b$," one integrates over the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: the Lebesgue measure of $(a,b)$ is $b-a$. It is supposed that $a<b$ but you could swap the order...

Comment: And are there measure-based integration theory for which the notion of orientation does make sense?

Comment: @fonfonx the question was about Lebesgue integration not Lebesgue measure. The way the Lebesgue measure is defined most certainly uses the ordering of the real numbers, but in defining $\int_X f$ there is never a presuppposed notion of ordering on $X$.

Comment: @Nixin the way Lebesgue integration is defined is based on Lebesgue measure. When we say that $\int \mathbb{1}_X \mathrm{d}\lambda = \lambda(S)$ we have to compute $\lambda(X)$. And the Lebesgue measure on real numbers implictly presuppose that real are ordered

Comment: @fonfonx Lebesgue integration refers the theory of integration on general measure spaces, see any source on it, for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration. There is *never* a supposition that the underlying space has to be ordered for Lebesgue integration to be well-defined. To define the Lebesgue *measure* one uses the ordering of the real numbers, though as I have stated before, this is not what the question is about at all.